# 404 Downloading OneDrive content from Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to download the content of a onedrive item via the microsoft api.  However, no matter the method I use, I get 404 responses.  Here is a reproduction of the problem in python/requests

```
import requests
import json

root_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
base_path = "/v1.0/<tenant_id>/users/<principal_name>/drive/"

token = "ALONGTOKEN"

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token}

r = requests.get(root_url + base_path + "/root/children", headers=headers)
listing = json.loads(r.text)
target = listing["value"][0]
print("Target node:")
print(json.dumps(target))
print("Target node id:")
print(target["id"])

r = requests.get(root_url + base_path + "items/" + target["id"], headers=headers)
print("Target metadata:")
print(r.text)

resp = json.loads(r.text)
download_url = resp["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"]
print("Target download url:")
print(download_url)

r = requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
print("Download response code:")
print(r.status_code)
print("Download response headers:")
print(r.headers)
print("Download response cookies:")
print(r.cookies)
print("Download response redirect history:")
print(r.history)
```

outputs the following:

```
Target node:
{"parentReference": {"driveId": "drive_id", "path": "/drive/root:", "id": "parent_id"}, "cTag": "\"c:{tag},1\"", "lastModifiedDateTime": "2016-08-24T17:32:45Z", "name": "birds.png", "createdDateTime": "2016-08-24T17:32:45Z", "image": {}, "webUrl": "https://org-my.sharepoint.com/personal/principal_name/Documents/birds.png", "lastModifiedBy": {"user": {"displayName": "User Name", "id": "user_id"}}, "eTag": "\"{etag},1\"", "createdBy": {"user": {"displayName": "User Name", "id": "user_id"}}, "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https://org-my.sharepoint.com/personal/principal_name/_layouts/15/download.aspx?guestaccesstoken=access_token&docid=did&expiration=2016-09-01T17%3a12%3a14.000Z&userid=uid&authurl=True&NeverAuth=True", "file": {"hashes": {}}, "id": "01L4SXJGJ2LR2PGPKJMVGZPHIADCAYJEFE", "size": 34038}

Target node id:
01L4SXJGJ2LR2PGPKJMVGZPHIADCAYJEFE

Target metadata:
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('principal_name')/drive/items/$entity","@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl":"https://org-my.sharepoint.com/personal/principal_name/_layouts/15/download.aspx?guestaccesstoken=accesstoken&docid=docid&expiration=2016-09-01T17%3a12%3a15.000Z&userid=uid&authurl=True&NeverAuth=True","createdBy":{"user":{"id":"user_id","displayName":"User Name"}},"createdDateTime":"2016-08-24T17:32:45Z","eTag":"\"{etag},1\"","id":"01L4SXJGJ2LR2PGPKJMVGZPHIADCAYJEFE","lastModifiedBy":{"user":{"id":"user_id","displayName":"User Name"}},"lastModifiedDateTime":"2016-08-24T17:32:45Z","name":"birds.png","webUrl":"https://org-my.sharepoint.com/personal/principal_name/Documents/birds.png","cTag":"\"c:{ctag},1\"","file":{"hashes":{}},"image":{},"parentReference":{"driveId":"drive_id","id":"parent_id","path":"/drive/root:"},"size":34038}

Target download url:
https://org-my.sharepoint.com/personal/principal_name/_layouts/15/download.aspx?guestaccesstoken=accesstoken&docid=docid&expiration=2016-09-01T17%3a12%3a15.000Z&userid=uid&authurl=True&NeverAuth=True

Download response code:
404

Download response headers:
{'Content-Length': '13702', 'SPIisLatency': '4', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'request-id': '288b9f9d-c04a-2000-133b-ebab2f6f332b', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices': '16.0.0.5625', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'SPRequestGuid': '288b9f9d-c04a-2000-133b-ebab2f6f332b', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'X-MS-InvokeApp': '1; RequireReadOnly', 'X-SharePointHealthScore': '0', 'SPRequestDuration': '297', 'SharePointError': '0', 'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Date': 'Thu, 01 Sep 2016 16:12:14 GMT', 'P3P': 'CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}

Download response cookies:
<RequestsCookieJar[]>

Download response redirect history:
[]
```

Which is to say that immediately following the link results in a 404, though it is supposed to download the file bytes.  I have reproduced this in java, python, bash/curl, and in the browser.  Can anybody help point out what I am doing wrong, or is this a problem with the microsoft graph api?

EDIT:

I can also reproduce the same 404 using the /drive/items/{item-id}/content endpoint described [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent).  The request to this endpoint results in a 302 redirect (as described in the documentation), which, when followed, results in the same 404 behavior as described above.

EDIT2:

Here are all the request-ids I could find in the response headers that looked useful for debugging from Microsoft's side.

For the 200 request on the item object: 'request-id': 'adfa3492-4825-439d-8e59-022f32e78244', 'client-request-id': 'adfa3492-4825-439d-8e59-022f32e78244'

For the 404 request on the download url: 'request-id': '33e09e9d-b0c2-2000-133c-304585c15000', 'SPRequestGuid': '33e09e9d-b0c2-2000-133c-304585c15000',

Additionally, the actual HTML returned from the 404 includes Correlation ID: a8e09e9d-a0bb-2000-133b-ef6fc8ac7015

Comment: Can you provide the "request-id" from the response headers?

Comment: Its e04e9d9d-9070-2000-133b-ef376013cbdc

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: the above request-id is for the 404 response.  Let me know if you want the request ID for the initial get on the object.

Comment: I too used the same graph api, but download worked out for me! My client is in java! Can you provide more details? Are you trying to download your own doc? Or do you have enough permissions?

Comment: @PradeepNeerukonda I am trying to download a document for a using using delegated permissions.  My AzureAD application has permissions to everything in the microsoft graph as well as sharepoint.  However, the downloadUrl property should require no authentication at all.  My understanding is that that link is publicly usable for a short period of time (minutes) after it is generated.  Please let me know if you think there is more info I should be providing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File download is currently only supported with **delegated** permissions (e.g. File.Read scope) as documented [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent). Your request was made with **application** permissions Files.Read.All and Files.ReadWrite.All, which we're gradually adding support for, but they're not yet fully functional and are not listed [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes).

Comment: Is that still true?

Comment: Is this still an open issue? Is there an ETA of when this will be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that item_id is in fact the ID of an item? If you are working off the collection returned by GET /v1.0/users//drive/items/, the collection will return an array of folder and item metadata. If you try your request against a folder, you will get the 404 as you've described. That's the only way that I can repro your issue. If that is not the issue, please provide the request/response trace so that we can see the error details.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response.  I am sure that item_id is the id of a file because the initial call returns a json object that includes the "file" property.  According the the documentation, this means that the object is a file.  I have added "EDIT2" that contains all the request response trace information that I could find, please let me know if there is something else I should be including.

Comment: @User1234567890 I can't use the RequestIds to look up your calls. Can you show us the initial call that is made? The one where you get the item_id? Please show the request, and sanitized (and potentially abbreviated) response body.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the follow-up.  Please look again at the code in my original question, specifically at the first requests.get call in which I request the item using the item_id.  The response to this call is a 200 with a full body describing the item, indicating that this is a valid item id. You can view this response in the second code block of my question. The issue I am having is that the downloadUrl provided with this item response resolves to a 404 rather than downloading the bytes of the file.  The 404 does not occur because of an incorrect item id.

Comment: Hi Michael, I updated the script above to reflect what you asked.  It now includes the code that lists through the root folder to find the target item.  Hopefully this will help clarify the problem.  Do you have any advice about how to further debug this issue?  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @User1234567890 I can't repro your issue. I'm successfully using the password grant flow to get the access token in a test case and accessing a resource owned by the calling account. In your case, I'm assuming that the caller is a service since you mention delegated permissions, and is access a resource in another account. Can you take the service out of the equation and repro the issue if you call with resource owner's access token?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks again for following up.  I am currently working on setting up the scenario that you describe.  However, it is essential to my application that we use delegated access to files.  Is this not currently supported by the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Delegated access is supported. There may be an issue with calls you are making in that scenario.

Comment: I'm developing a Daemon type application for OneDrive for Business.

I can get information like /drive/root/children, or /drive/item for any users, but I can not get the 'content'

For ex, this work,

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>/drive/item/<itemid>`

This returns 404

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>/drive/item/<itemid>/content`

@Michael Mainer - MSFT, any suggestions?

Comment: @Locke Please open a new a post with the steps that you have taken to get the file contents. This way, any answers will be more discoverable. Please link to any resources you have tried. Please show the request and response, and identify the client library you are using, if any. Also, please verify that the item that you are trying to download is a file, and that it has content.